# How to create command line shortcut that opens a specific directory?

Tags: windows, command-line, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcut to command prompt pointing to specific folder](https://superuser.com/questions/254525/shortcut-to-command-prompt-pointing-to-specific-folder)

My command line shortcut defaults to `C:\Users\Username`.  I would like to be able to create a shortcut that when launched will default to something like `C:\Path\To\Visual Studio 2010\Projects` so I can save myself some keystrokes when I need to issue some mercurial commands.

Comment: @techie007 Wow, that was so easy I feel kind of silly.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: No problem. The 'related' list on the right helped me find it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `doskey` command, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKey

In your case, this might do the trick:

```
doskey gotoprojects="cd C:\Path\To\Visual Studio 2010\Projects"
```

(haven't tried out myself, don't have a Windows pc available ATM)

Next, you can use the `gotoprojects` command.