# Can't set WIndows 11 shortcut start-in & run as admin

Tags: shortcuts, windows-11

I've been looking for hours - lots of information about how to run as admin, but have yet to scry the magic word combination that would allow me to enter the shortcut's "Start-in" location

[image: Start-in disabled]

or set to "run as admin"

This is a new installation performed commercially after Win10 lost all of my printers & Microsoft was unable to restore them.

The Target is "Command Prompt", reached/generated by Start>Programs>Windows Tools (!) --> Control Panel>System and Security>Windows Tools Right-click "Command Prompt" Create shortcut >On desktop.

(!) : I have two "Windows Tools" entries, The top one leads to another submenu on which "Command Prompt" does not appear. The other opens "Control Panel>System and Security>Windows Tools".

Having created that shortcut, right-click and select "properties" result is the screens shown above (having selected the "Shortcut" tab and the "advanced" button respectively.

If I try using Control Panel>Windows Tools, get to the same position with the shortcut.

But I found a solution - posted as an answer...

[image: Can't click this (with any effect)]

It all worked in Win10.

I have admin privileges, and UAC has been disabled.

Comment: In order for me to test myself can you provide more information on the shortcut itself?

Comment: What's this shortcut about? Please tell what's the target command of this shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Start>Programs>Windows System right-click on "Command Prompt" Send-to Desktop

Generated another "Shortcut" where the "Start-in" could be edited, the "Advanced" allowed "Run as administrator" to be selected, as well as the other necessary items (Quickedit, insert mode, colours, screen layout, buffers, font & so on) were available. These also appeared to be available by right-clicking the top bar of a "command Prompt" window, although I've no idea whether the selections made would have survived terminating the session.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when creating a shortcut to cmd.exe.
I think this is a duplicate of: [How to open Command Prompt in a specific folder as Administrator?](https://superuser.com/questions/1067901/how-to-open-command-prompt-in-a-specific-folder-as-administrator)

In essence you would need to use the /k option after cmd.exe followed by the cd "path to directory" to get the desired result.